# MvvmCross ViewModel Command that Handles Dynamic Fragment

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In the MvvmCross N=26 tutorial, dynamic fragments are loaded into a frame via button click event in the View (code snippet below). However, I'm trying to figure out how handle the click event in the ViewModel and not in the View. After the button is clicked, how do I know the button was clicked and in the View, load the correct fragment in the frame?

For instance, I may have 10 fragments and one frame in the FirstView xml. I want to be able to load any of those 10 fragments in that frame based on a property of a object referenced in the FirstViewModel. Can I check that property in the View and load the fragment that I want from the 10 fragments available? (i.e. remove the but1.Click event in the View and still run the transaction based on the value of the object in the ViewModel)

```
but1.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var dNew = new DubFrag()
                    {
                        ViewModel = ((SecondViewModel) ViewModel).Sub
                    };
                var trans3 = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                trans3.Replace(Resource.Id.subframe1, dNew);
                trans3.AddToBackStack(null);
                trans3.Commit();
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach you suggest of mapping a vm property to which fragment to show should work, yes.

To use this, just subscribe to property changed in your view code (there are some weak reference helper classes and extension methods to assist with this)

---

Alternatively, this blog post - http://enginecore.blogspot.ca/2013/06/more-dynamic-android-fragments-with.html?m=1 - introduces a mini framework that allows navigating by fragments.

A similar approach is used in the Shakespeare sample in the mvvmcross-tutorials fragments sample.

It should be possible to adapt that code to your needs